# Minimum size of subarray whose sum is k

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

I need to find minimum subarray length whose sum is *greater or equal* to `k`. Array will have only positive numbers.

eg

> Input: `target = 7`, `nums = [2,3,1,2,4,3]` Output: 2 Explanation: The
> subarray [4,3] has the minimal length under the problem constraint.

In my code, for Input: `target = 7`, `nums = [2,3,1,2,4,3]`
I am getting answer as `3`, but the right answer is `2`. How to fix it?

```
public int minSubArrayLen(int target, int[] nums) {
    
        int arraySize = nums.length;
        int end = 0; // end of subarray
        int start = 0; // start of subarray
        int minArraySize = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int sum = 0;

        while (end < arraySize) {
            sum = sum + nums[end];
            if (sum == target) {
                minArraySize = Math.min(minArraySize, end - start + 1);
                end++;
            } else if (sum > target) {
                while (sum > target) {
                    sum = sum - nums[start];
                    start++;
                }
                  
                  end++;


                if (sum == target)
                {
                  minArraySize  = Math.min(minArraySize, end - start +1);
                }

                    

            } else if (sum < target) {
                end++;

            }
        }
     
         
        return minArraySize;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest turning outer `while` into `for` which can help to *simplify* the (**Java**) code:

```
public int minSubArrayLen(int target, int[] nums) {
    //TODO: check for nums == null, target <= 0
    
    int result = 0;
    
    int left = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    
    for (int right = 0; right < nums.length; ++right) {
        sum += nums[right];
                 
        // if sum is large enough we should subtract from the left   
        while (sum >= target) {
            result = result == 0
                ? right - left + 1
                : Math.min(result, right - left + 1); 

            sum -= nums[left++];
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: i tried your soltion.Test cases are failing
https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-size-subarray-sum/

Comment: @Pale Blue Dot: I see; we should return `0` in case subarry is not found. I've edited the answer

Comment: It working.I am not able to under for input `Target :11 and Nums[] : {1,2,3,4,5} .How the output is 3?

Comment: @Pale Blue Dot: quotation from Leetcode: "... which the sum is **greater** than or **equal** ... ", **bold** is mine, that's why we have `3` as the answer since `3 + 4 + 5 >= 11` (note `>=` instead of `==`)

Comment: Ah i missed  the "greater than " part.No wonder my code wasn't working for all  inputs.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After advancing the start you have to check if you hit the traget before you increment `end++;`. You can also avoid some code duplication with a goto.

```
int minSubArrayLen(int target, std:vector<int> nums) {
    int arraySize = nums.size();
    int end = 0; // end of subarray
    int start = 0; // start of subarray
    int minArraySize = INT_MAX;
    int sum = 0;

    while (end < arraySize) {
        sum = sum + nums[end];
    again:
        if (sum == target) {
            minArraySize = Math.min(minArraySize, end - start + 1);
        } else if (sum > target) {
            sum = sum - nums[start];
            start++;
            goto again;
        } 
        end++;
    }
 
     
    return minArraySize;
    
}
```

Comment: `else if ( sum > target) {
    while (start<= end && sum > target) {
     sum = sum - nums[start];
     start++;
    }
                if (sum == target) {
                  minArraySize = Math.min(minArraySize, end - start + 1);
                  end++;
                 }`
I did the same thing.But algorithm is still not working

Comment: works for me https://godbolt.org/z/zhjPvWej6

Comment: Just ran your code inleetcode.Its failing  some of the test cases (just like my solution).`https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-size-subarray-sum/`

Comment: Maybe you need to handle `target <= 0`?

Comment: Nope, it's the "not found" case in Example 3. We return IN_MAX but expected is 0. Which frankly makes no sense.

Comment: No target is the sum passed as param. And its a read only only variable

Comment: .I guess you are right.There is some issue with test cases it seems?
`Target=11 and array [1,2,3,4,5]` O/P expected is 3.Which doesnt make sense

Comment: just add `if (minArraySize == INT_MAX) return 0;`

Comment: I have already added that in the end of the code